# Telethon user бот

Tags: python, telethon

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

# Замените значения ниже на свои API ID, API HASH и токен бота
api_id = ''
api_hash = ''


client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(id))
async def main(event):
    await client.forward_messages(id, event.message)

async def main():введите сюда код
    await client.start()
    print("Client has started.")
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Нужно сделать чтобы при пересылке не показывалось "Переслано от"